# How to find certain string in database

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to find certain string in database - I'm using this code but couldn't get the result needed

Is there any suggestions to alternative code  Or Edits ?

I've tried this code

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%search_string%';`

Thanks

Comment: That is the way you do it.  "LIKE" does a case-sensitive search, so case must match.